# PyTorch Dataset / Dataloader from random source

Tags: pytorch

I have a source of random (non-deterministic, non-repeatable) data, that I'd like to wrap in Dataset and Dataloader for PyTorch training.  How can I do this?

`__len__` is not defined, as the source is infinite (with possible repition).
`__getitem__` is not defined, as the source is non-deterministic.

Comment: You can define `__len__` as the number of data you want to draw in one epoch, and let `__getitem__` return any data (just ignoring the given index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining a custom dataset class, you'd ordinarily subclass `torch.utils.data.Dataset` and define `__len__()` and `__getitem__()`.

However, for cases where you want sequential but not random access, you can use an [iterable-style dataset](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#iterable-style-datasets). To do this, you instead subclass [`torch.utils.data.IterableDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.IterableDataset) and define `__iter__()`. Whatever is returned by `__iter__()` should be a proper iterator; it should maintain state (if necessary) and define `__next__()` to obtain the next item in the sequence. `__next__()` should `raise StopIteration` when there's nothing left to read. In your case with an infinite dataset, it never needs to do this.

Here's an example:

```
import torch

class MyInfiniteIterator:
    def __next__(self):
        return torch.randn(10)

class MyInfiniteDataset(torch.utils.data.IterableDataset):
    def __iter__(self):
        return MyInfiniteIterator()

dataset = MyInfiniteDataset()
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size = 32)

for batch in dataloader:
    # ... Do some stuff here ...
    # ...

    # if some_condition:
    #     break
```